# Getting Integer Overflow Error in Rest API

Tags: java, rest, integer-overflow

This is one of the example where on two parameter isForcedUpdate and recordCount is being attached by larger Integer values.The scenario is larger int value is coming from client side to my controller. That is throwing integeroverflow. Any solution what could best approach to handle Integer overflow error  in rest api ? Should I perform validation on my controller for every Integer or what could be the best way ?

[image: This is the Image]

Comment: Why don't you want to change your api field type, from Integer to Long or BigInteger?

Comment: I can do that but using Long every where instead of Integer is not a good approach. That means I cant use integer any where in project and only Long I have to use. This is not a good way . What should be the ideal practice that people follow in Rest API For handling integeroverflow error.? At controller layer ?